# Populating input forms with json data on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to populate a form on a button click, so for example a user clicks a button and then it populates the inputs with the button id's information from a json page. I have added what I need in the jquery belo

Here's my javascript, which doesn't have an onclick, which I need it to, but need it t

**jquery script**

```
   (i need an on click perform this action)
    $.get('<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/employment_json/(i need this to be the value of the button)',function(d){
        $("input[name='json_name']").val(d.name);
        $("input[name='json_country']").val(d.country);
        $("input[name='json_start']").val(d.date_start);
        $("input[name='json_end']").val(d.date_end);
        $("input[name='json_duration']").val(d.duration);
        $("input[name='json_description']").val(d.description);
    },'json');
```

Here's sample data of the inputs:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field-1" class="control-label">
            <?php echo System::translate("Employment name"); ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" disabled name="json_name" class="form-control" id="field-1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field-2" class="control-label">
            <?php echo System::translate("Employment Country"); ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" disabled name="json_country" class="form-control" id="field-2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field-2" class="control-label">
            <?php echo System::translate("Start Date"); ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" disabled name="json_start" class="form-control" id="field-2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field-2" class="control-label">
            <?php echo System::translate("End date"); ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" disabled name="json_end" class="form-control" id="field-2">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field-2" class="control-label">
            <?php echo System::translate("Employment Duration"); ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" disabled name="json_duration" class="form-control" id="field-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

And lastly, but not least,

**Json sample**

> {"employment":{"name":"test","duration":"12","date_end":"2015-07-01","date_start":"2014-07-07","country":"America","description":"This is just a test description of no important value. Have a nice day."}}

Comment: so basically are you asking how to add a click handler??

Comment: Yes but also to get the id value of the button to use here: dashboard/employment_json/(i need this to be the value of the button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
$('.myButtonClass').on('click', function(e){
    var url = '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/employment_json/' + e.target.id;
    $.get(url,function(d){
        $("input[name='json_name']").val(d.name);
        $("input[name='json_country']").val(d.country);
        $("input[name='json_start']").val(d.date_start);
        $("input[name='json_end']").val(d.date_end);
        $("input[name='json_duration']").val(d.duration);
        $("input[name='json_description']").val(d.description);
    },'json');
});
```

Obviously you have to change

```
$('.myButtonClass')
```

here you have to use the class or id of the button you want to bind the action to.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be populating the form inputs.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied and pasted and renamed the mybuttonclass.

Comment: Well I guessed it right. I will update my answer to let you understand

Comment: Still doesn't work, I renamed both the button and the $('mybuttonclass') and the inputs are still empty

Comment: could you update your code, on the question? also if you log the result of get did you what you expect?